# How to open another view on button click without creating a Window in Titanium?

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have to views: view1.xml, view2.xml. Both the files are already existing. I have a button in view1.xml and when user clicks on that button, I want to load view2.xml file in the same window. I do not want to create another window to load that view. I think I need to do add event listener to that button and load the view but I do not know how to do that.

I did something like this

```
$.next.addEventListener('click', function() {
var myView = Alloy.createController('nextView').getView();
$.main_window.add(myView);
});
```

Comment: You should provide some code examples showing what you have, so it will be easier to provide precise solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this

```
var view=Alloy.createController('mycoolwindow').getView();
win.add(view);
```

You have to add the view in window instead of opening it like window

Comment: It adds the view to the same window below the current view. I want it to dismiss the previous view and show the content of the new view only in that window.

Comment: remove the previous view and then add the new one